# Changing the protocol from HTTPs to HTTP

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using tortoisesvn and the file I commit turns into a URL with the protocol of HTTPs, how do I change it to HTTP?

Comment: AFAIK, it's considered to be a new repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
svn relocate
```

to switch the protocol.

Please note that svn will emit a warning if the repositories are different (according to a UID) and you can mess up all if the repositories are really different.